# Recursion operation in Pre-order tree traversal

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, tree

Pre-order traversal is simple recursive procedure. I am perplexed with two implementations behaving differently.

**Input** passed to both implementations are:

```
[1,null,2,3]
[]
[1]
```

**Expected output for above input-**

```
[1,2,3]
[]
[1]
```

**1st implementation-**

```
class Solution:
    ans=[]
    def preorderTraversal(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[int]:
        if root is None:
            return
        self.ans.append(root.val)
        self.preorderTraversal(root.left)
        self.preorderTraversal(root.right)
        
        return self.ans
```

**Output-**

```
[1,2,3]
[]
[1,2,3,1]
```

**2nd implementation-**

```
class Solution:
    def preorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        self.ans=[]
        def preorder(root):
            if root is None:
                return
            self.ans.append(root.val)
            preorder(root.left)
            preorder(root.right)
        preorder(root)
        return self.ans
```

**This gives correct output**

What is wrong with the 1st implementation?

Answer (score 1):

In 1st implementation you define class field ans shared between class instances. Thus when you run the code for last example ans has value [1, 2, 3].

In 2nd implementation you define instance field. In this case ans belong to instance, not class.

Comment: Thanks, its clear to me now what went wrong (also referred: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-34-class-or-static-variables-in-python/)

But there is one thing that bugs me that on returning class variable **ans**  wasn't it is supposed to give [1,2,3] as output for [ ] as input?

Comment: Sorry. I dont get the point. Can you clarify what do you mean saying "ans wasn't it is supposed to give [1,2,3] as output for [ ] as input"?